# How do I access another argument in a default argument in a python dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I am trying to derive the default value of `id_` from `name` and vice versa.

```
@dataclass
class Item:
    id_ = NAME_TO_ID[name]
    name = ID_TO_NAME[id_]
```

I should be able to call the class like so:

```
Item(id_=123)
Item(name='foo')
```

If possible, I would also like the class to raise an error when both `id_` and `name` are provided.

```
Item(id_=123, name='foo')  # ValueError: id_ and name cannot be provided together
```

Any recommendations on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: You should use a standard python class instead

Comment: Yeah, I am. I'm just trying to see if there's a way to approach this with dataclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use write a [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) method to do these validations

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Item:
    id_: int = field(default=None)
    name: str = field(default=None)
    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.id_ is None and self.name is None:
            raise TypeError("You must provide exactly one of name or id_")
        if self.id_ is not None and self.name is not None:
            raise TypeError("You must provide exactly one of name or id_")
        if self.id_ is not None:
            self.name = id_to_name(self.id_)
        else:
            self.id_ = name_to_id(self.name)
```

Comment: How is that any better than just a `__init__` with the validation for both fields? We don't need to push dataclasses for everything

Comment: @JBernardo Because if you have other fields, you can use the generated `__init__` for them.  This is a question explicitly about dataclasses

Comment: Was that tag just added? The comment the OP made seemed to imply that he was just trying to see if a dataclass solution makes sense, but in my opinion it's a little overkill. That is just my opinion, however.

Comment: Yes (by me).  The title was always "How do I access another argument in a default argument in a python dataclass?" though

Answer (score 0):

Would something as simple as the below work for you?

At object instantiation, check if too much or too little data was provided, then define a property that will compute the value if necessary?

```
class Item ():
    def __init__(self, id: int =None, name:str= None):
        if all ([name, id]):
            raise ValueError ("id_ and name cannot be provided together")
        elif not any ([name, id]):
            raise ValueError ("name or id must be provided for Item instantiation")
        else:
            self._name = name
            self._id = id
    @property
    def name (self) -> str:
        if self._name is None:
            #Compute the value and return it
            pass #remove this once you figure out your algorithm
        else:
            return self._name
    @property
    def id (self) ->int:
        if self._id is None:
            #Compute the value and return it
            pass #remove this once you figure out your algorithm
       else:
           return self._id
```

Note that you must also take into consideration what a valid value is. In my provided example case, it is not sufficient if you consider integer `0` a valid `id`, and an empty string `""` a valid `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `__init__` function of your `class`.

For example,

```
class Item:
    # define __init__ such that it has a condition when both id_ and name are supplied
    # a ValueError is raised
    def __init__(self, id_, name=None):
        if (id_ and name):
            # raise error because both were supplied
            raise ValueError
        if (id_):
            # assign name and id
        elif (name):
            # assign name and id
```

Here, though, the user has to pass a value for both.  You can simply supply `False` or `None` or some falsy value so that it is passed over and the ValueError isn't thrown.